# Rlike MariaDB Query slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mariadb

I have a query which Im satified with the results but not for its performance the query is, I want to select some words from a text (partial words not allowed) (i.e. I want to select : "dog" not "dogs")

```
SELECT name FROM texts WHERE name rlike '[[:<:]]text[[:>:]]' LIMIT 0, 50;
```

I have tested the same select with "like '% text %' " is much more fast but do not selects correctly word boundaries as "text." (ending with .) or with !, starting the sentence,....there are too many possibilities...

there is any way to improve/modify my query with the same results?

Thanks

Comment: You should look into a full text index:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-text-index-overview/.

Comment: What about `name like '%text%' and name rlike '[[:<:]]text[[:>:]]'`? The first condition is redundant, but may improve the performance.

Comment: The problem with full text index is that split dashed words, i.e "well-known" searches for (well,known) and not just "well-known" how to correct that?

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('well-known' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND RLIKE '[[:<:]]well-known[[:>:]]'
```

`FULLTEXT` is faster than `LIKE`; `LIKE` is faster than `RLIKE`.

The problem is with the exceptions (short words, stop words, etc) of `FULLTEXT`.  If practical, have your app look at the search word to decide wither to do this `FULLTEXT AND` trick or to use Paul's `LIKE AND` trick.

The reason for sluggishness...  In your original query (just `RLIKE`), every row must be read, and every `name` must be scanned for the "text".

`FULLTEXT` is faster (perhaps a lot faster) because it can use an index to go straight to the rows with the "text".

`LIKE` is faster than `RLIKE` because the algorithm is less complex.  (But it still must fetch every `name`.)